# Calcular tamaño total de todos los archivos regulares en C

Tags: c

Estoy intentando calcular la suma del tamaño de todos los archivos de una lista de directorios. El caso es que no consigo que la suma sea correcta. Utilizo una variable de tipo double para guardar el total.

```
double suma;
char **almacendir;
```

Tengo una matriz con los nombres de los directorios almacenados y la llamada a la función que calcula el tamaño seria esta.

```
for(contador=0;contador<numdir;contador++){
    analizardirectorio(almacendir[contador],&suma);
```

Y la funcion en si es la siguiente:

```
void analizardirectorio (char *directorio, double *size){
struct stat st;
DIR *d;
struct dirent *dir;
char buf[512];

d=opendir(directorio);
if(d){
    while((dir=readdir(d))!=NULL){
        if (dir->d_type == DT_REG){ //compruebo si es un archivo regular
            sprintf(buf,"%s/%s",directorio,dir->d_name);
            if((stat(buf, &st))== -1) //cargo los datos de archivo 
                perror("stat()");
            else{
                *size+=((double)st.st_size)/(1024*1024);//conversion a megas
            }

        }
    }
}else{
    perror("opendir()");
}
closedir(d);
}
```

Como se ve hago una conversion desde off_t a double para pasar el tamaño de bytes a megas y poder guardar mayor cantidad de datos. Aún así me fallan los resultados y no logro entender el por qué. Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Estás inicializando `size` en algún momento? Si la respueta es no... ya sabes lo que toca... si es sí, piensa que los archivos suelen ser más grandes que su contenido y el motivo es que los discos suelen estar paginados, siendo una página la unidad mínima de tamaño para ese disco... prueba a depurar el programa y comprueba el valor de `st_size` para cada fichero... a ver si coincide con lo que esperas

Comment: "*me fallan los resultados*". ¿Qué falla? ¿Qué esperabas recibir y qué estás recibiendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No entiendo por qué, la [documentación de Code Wiki respecto a la estructura `stat`](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:struct-stat) no muestra información del campo `st_size`. Por suerte existen [otras fuentes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) para consultaro:

```
struct stat {
   dev_t     st_dev;         /* ID of device containing file */
   ino_t     st_ino;         /* Inode number */
   mode_t    st_mode;        /* File type and mode */
   nlink_t   st_nlink;       /* Number of hard links */
   uid_t     st_uid;         /* User ID of owner */
   gid_t     st_gid;         /* Group ID of owner */
   dev_t     st_rdev;        /* Device ID (if special file) */
   off_t     st_size;        /* Total size, in bytes */
   blksize_t st_blksize;     /* Block size for filesystem I/O */
   blkcnt_t  st_blocks;      /* Number of 512B blocks allocated */

   /* Since Linux 2.6, the kernel supports nanosecond
      precision for the following timestamp fields.
      For the details before Linux 2.6, see NOTES. */

   struct timespec st_atim;  /* Time of last access */
   struct timespec st_mtim;  /* Time of last modification */
   struct timespec st_ctim;  /* Time of last status change */

#define st_atime st_atim.tv_sec      /* Backward compatibility */
#define st_mtime st_mtim.tv_sec
#define st_ctime st_ctim.tv_sec
};
```

Viendo que, según la documentación original, el campo `st_size` de la estructura `stat` es el tamaño total en bytes, vemos que tu conversión a debería ser correcta. Sin embargo no concretas tu problema (no dices qué valor esperabas y qué valor recibes en su lugar), te propongo una alternativa con la que comparar resultados.

#### Propuesta.

Aplica el [principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica) y separa la tarea de recorrer un directorio y la tarea de obtener el tamaño de un archivo:

```
double tamanoarchivo (char *archivo) {
    double result = 0.;

    if (FILE *f = fopen(archivo, "r")) {
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        result = ftell(f);
        fclose(f);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Esta alternativa usa [`fopen`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) y [`fseek`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) para el cálculo de tamaño, sería usada así:

```
double analizardirectorio (char *directorio) {
    char buf[512] = {'\0'};
    double size = .0;

    if (DIR *d = opendir(directorio)) {
        struct dirent *dir = NULL;
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            if (dir->d_type == DT_REG) {
                sprintf(buf,"%s/%s",directorio,dir->d_name);
                size += (tamanoarchivo(buf) / (1024 * 1024));
            }
        }
    } else {
        perror("opendir()");
    }

    closedir(d);
}
```

Quisiera destacar los siguientes cambios realizados:

1. Todas las variables están inicializadas, eso evita errores.
2. Tanto la función `analizardirectorio` como la función `tamanoarchivo` devuelven un `double`, no tiene sentido pasar un parámetro de retorno pudiendo devolverlo como resultado.
3. Dado que `tamanoarchivo` devuelve `double` no es necesario hacer conversión explícita en la división pues toda la sentencia se pasa a `double` implícitamente.